# Get Facebook event large cover photo

Tags: facebook, events, cover

I am trying to import a facebook event with js. So far everything works perfectly fine. The only thing is FB returns an object with

cover.source => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/12669607_226852920986152_2794185577349660626_n.png?oh=73ee451aa4181b39f18380f2d963a59d&oe=57C7F96F

This is a smaller version of the original image. When I remove 's720x720/', it sometimes returns the larger image but not always, while there is one available.
I checked by manually clicking on event cover and open image in new tab.

Is there a way to get the largest size of this cover photo?

https://scontent-amt2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12669607_226852920986152_2794185577349660626_n.png?oh=70698f32e16e25ea47a2c8d0d45703c9&oe=57D1650D

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Here's a solution for getting larger event image via Android SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39951446/2162226