# Facebook Graph API getCover not working anymore

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

### STORY

I have an app on playstore that downloads the cover photo of the user and sets as the backgound of the drawer.

**What Happend?**

It stopped working i was using the link below it was working like a charm, but it's not working anymore, now i only get the id of the user but no cover

**What was working before ?**

`https://graph.facebook.com/{my id}?fields=cover&access_token={my token}`

### Troubleshoot

I thought that maybe was something that i did without noticing in my code, so downloaded my app from the playstore and i got the same problem the cover is not being downloded so at this point im almost sure that the problem is something to do with facebook itself

I belive is something to do with permissions because i get a responce but not the `source` of the cover but if it was working with my user i don't know why isn't this working anymore

### Failed Attemps to fix the problem

I went to Facebook Developers page and i tried this

```
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"...?fields=cover", 
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

Sadly this didn't work, in facebook developers page they show this `"...?fields={fieldname_of_type_CoverPhoto}"` i belive `fieldname coverPhoto` is `cover` like i see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

### Result

This will log

```
{Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error:
{HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) 
Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ...}}
```

I tried to remove the 3 dots and i tried to add `me?fields=cover` got this:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error:
{HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) 
Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: fields=cover}}
```

## EDIT

I tried this

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender,cover,picture.type(large)");
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
          new GraphRequest.Callback() {
          @Override
          public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
               if (response != null) {
                  try {
                     JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                     Log.d(TAG, data.toString());
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Log.d(TAG, "ERROR");
                }
           }
        }
  }).executeAsync();
```

this prints all my information but no cover

Comment: Here's a solution for getting event cover image: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39951446/2162226

Comment: but you still need the `user_photos` permission right? when i was chating with facebook devs they told me that you are not supposed to get the cover photo without this permission if you can it's a bug on the facebook side

Comment: for my app, here are the permissions I used: `"public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_events"` in the login call: `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(..)`

Comment: i recomend you to add  `user_photos` what happend to me can happen to you aswell, i published my app and everything was working fine, but stopped working for no reson, i had to submit my app for revison and implement a provisory solution in the mean time, they explicitly told me that `cover` is a part of the `user_photos` if you are able to get the cover without this permission is because `user_photos` is not being enforced due to a bug, you can check it here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1581628792141976/ if you don't have `user_photos` your app may stop working soon

Comment: hmm , that's interesting.  Thank you for the heads up there, I appreciate it

Comment: I went to that page and I saw that there were new comments there I don't now if you can see it says confidential message on my side but you can actually get the cover photo without that permission he said that they added the permission to the cover by mistake and it's now fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue

It seems that now we need to use `user_photos` permission, i belive this was something changed recently because my app was on the playstore for almost a month working perfectly without `user_photos`

Remeber that you need to request a new permisson, you can do that with this

```
if(!AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("user_photos")) {
     LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
     this,
     Arrays.asList("user_photos"));
}
```

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue

Comment: yes i was able to fix it i contacted facebook and they said that i need to use `user_photos` they said the reason why this was working without this permission may be because of a bug that was fixed recently that was allowing to get photos without the permission

Comment: I think your problem is that you forgot to re-request the permission to your account, you can't just add the permission to the login button you need to re-request the permission, i edited my awnser that code will request the permission to an existing account, If you are using my code you are good to go to get the cover you just need to use ` response.getJSONObject().getString("cover");` to get the url of the cover

Comment: Many thanks Tiago for your valuable time. I uninstalled the app and relogin with old user or new facebook user but still i am not able to get cover pic.
I debugged the code and found permission of "user_photos" to true.
If i use graph explorer then if i set version 2.3 there then i am able to get cover pic but if i go to 2.7 which is latest then i am not able to get it.

And in Android Facebook sdk i am not giving any version. I am attaching my code in next comment

Comment: Please help me on this i am stuck due to this

Comment: Post a question here and send me the link so i can understand the code with better formating, i will try to help you and you may get help from other users aswell, side note, i am using v2.7

Comment: Thanks Tiago . please find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557326/not-able-to-fetch-cover-pic-from-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Earlier in Facebooks API, it was possible to get the cover photo of a user when accessing graph API, by adding "cover" as a value to the GET parameter "fields" as you were doing (?fields=cover). This were previously valid.

However Facebook replaced "cover" with "UserCoverPhoto" and then finally removed the possibility to retrieve the cover photo from the user API version 3.2 as seen in the following official link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user
[image: 3.2 facebook api]

Even the oldest allowed facebook API version 2.8 does not have this feature.

Sadly you have to build another solution.

You would have to use the "user/photos" API and then allowing them to select what photo to use as a cover in your application. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

A non-recommended solution and probably against TOS and will get you banned would be to build a solution around the API for non-private users.